# How Can I compile/run a single CPP file in Codelite?

Tags: c++

I installed Codelite IDE in my laptop. But I couldn't run any code in my IDE.Please help me. Here I provide what happens when I press f5. and my settings too. [This happens when I press f5](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u2soT.png) and [Outcomes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/E5F71.png), [Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/caX7Z.png)

Comment: As it stated in the error message , you should add the option "file" or "exec-file" to your build config with the name of the output executable . I've never worked with codelite but there should be some build configuration somewhere. And I think you should add the name of output program in it like " a.out "

Comment: For me in the in the " Project settings -> General " there's  an option named " Executable to Run / Debug " it should be something like this : " $(WorkspacePath)/build-$(WorkspaceConfiguration)/bin/$(OutputFile)" by default.